# update webdriver-manager errno: -54, code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-manager, e2e

I work in a Lerna repo and want to do `npx webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=98.0.4758.80` for my e2e Tests

I tried as well `npx webdriver-manager update`
and `npx ./packages/testing/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update`

I always get this result:

```
npx: installed 88 in 4.393s
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.1.8
[13:39:20] I/file_manager - creating folder /Users/Prename.Lastname/.npm/_npx/97900/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[13:39:20] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/Prename.Lastname/.npm/_npx/97900/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[13:39:20] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/Prename.Lastname/.npm/_npx/97900/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[13:39:20] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/Prename.Lastname/.npm/_npx/97900/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Request instance at:
    at Request.onRequestError (/Users/Prename.Lastname/.npm/_npx/97900/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

What I already tried:

- `npx webdriver-manager clean`
- installed webdriver-manager globally for all users (and again uninstall)
- removed all node_modules and ran again `npm i`
- searched through `npx webdriver-manager update-help`

Does anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know why but it worked now
.. here what I've done:

1. `npm uninstall webdriver-manager`
2. `npm i`
3. `npx webdriver-manager clean`

and then `npx ./packages/testing/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update`